# Woocommerce sandbox paypal show order status payment pending

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

Even checkout process is completed using Paypal Sandbox, order status shows Payment Pending.

My configuration is wrong?

Comment: What is the transaction type set to for the payment? Authorize or Capture?

Comment: Payment action is Capture.

Comment: Are you familiar with IPN?  It sounds like your IPN updates aren't working properly.  You can check IPN History in PayPal to verify this.

Comment: I am not familiar with IPN. How can I chek IPN History, Please?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues, could be lots of things but I wasn't aware that in case of **physical products** *woocommerce* doesn't complete the order upon payment, that's because you should pack and send to the customer still so required some action from the seller.

in **class-wc-order.php** core woocommerce you can find this function

```
public function payment_complete( $transaction_id = '' ) {
        ...
                $this->set_status( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', $this->needs_processing() ? 'processing' : 'completed', $this->get_id(), $this ) );
                ...
}
```

the **needs_processing()** will return *true* if the product is not virtual.

I changed this behaviour with a simple hook on filter **woocommerce_order_item_needs_processing** that you can find inside the function *needs_processing()*

```
/**
 * this hooks turn status complete for every order upon payment.
 */

add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_needs_processing','my_filter');

//see class-wc-order line 1368 to understand the return value
function my_filter(){
    return false;
}
```

but really, this issue can be lots of thing so this is not your case then have a look to the woocommerce pay pal doc here https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/paypal-standard/#section-21